# Google Webcache 404 error

Tags: seo, 404, soft-404

We recently migrated our web platform from php application to nodejs react application. Ever since we are facing a major drop in organic traffic from google search. While debugging found an issue where our site's google webcache is through below error

[image]

This error was when trying to access link - bit.ly/2upsOrO

changing the link from https to http is working
i.e link bit.ly/2upT9pt is giving proper cached content.

Also weird part is changing the domain to any blah domain is giving cache content,
i.e link bit.ly/2uoERpe is giving proper cached content.

Couldn't understand the issue, kindly help me debug the same, also let me know if further information is needed.